# Form of Hypergeometric Differential Equation - possible mistake?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I'm performing a close critical study of David Nelson's *Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics* (4th ed., 2008).

Under the entry **hypergeometric differential equation**, it suggests the form:
$$x (1 - x) \dfrac {\mathrm d^2 \phi} {\mathrm d x^2} + [c - (a + b - 1) x] \dfrac {\mathrm d \phi} {\mathrm d x} - a b \phi = 0$$

However, everywhere else I look, I see it defined as:
$$x (1 - x) \dfrac {\mathrm d^2 \phi} {\mathrm d x^2} + [c - (a + b + 1) x] \dfrac {\mathrm d \phi} {\mathrm d x} - a b \phi = 0$$

I suspect, but would like to be certain, that Nelson's presentation is in fact incorrect, or whether it's a variant format which is equally acceptable as a representational format.

Before I report on this as an acual error, can it be confirmed that it is in fact wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Any homogenous linear equation of second order with singular  points $(0,1,\infty)$ $$x(1-x)f'' + (a + b x) f'[x] +c f[x]=0$$ is a hypergeometric differential equation, the regular solution at (0,1) being the hypergemetric series $$\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{b^2+2 b+4 c+1}-\frac{b}{2}-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{b^2+2 b+4 c+1}-\frac{b}{2}-\frac{1}{2};a;x\right).$$

Only the second standard form
$$f'(x) (c-x (a+b+1))-a b f(x)+(1-x) x f''(x)=0$$
yields the simple form of the parameters
$$\, _2F_1\left(a,b,c,x\right)$$
that generalizes the geometric series

```
   Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

$$\sum_n \frac{a_n b_n}{c_n n!} \ x^n = 1+\frac{a b x}{c}+\frac{a (a+1) b (b+1) x^2}{2 c (c+1)}+\frac{a (a+1) (a+2) b (b+1) (b+2) x^3}{6 c (c+1) (c+2)}+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: So what you're suggesting is that in the context of a general mathematical dictionary, ostensibly for school and university students, the form with the minus sign instead of the plus sign *does* appear to be a "mistake"? It wouldn't be the first - in fact I've identified 31 mistakes up to this point.

Comment: Formulas differing from their presentations in the online sources NIST handbook, MathWorld, Wikipedia should be corrected. All three sources are easily checked in Wolframs Mathematica (and vice versa sometimes). Some historically differing notations may exist, but thats a field for historians of mathematics (as the author, seems to be one of them)